# make loop script shell to convert videos?

Tags: shell

I have this script code to convert mkv video to mp4 from one directory ..

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script to convert all video .mkv to .mp4 with reduce size video

SourceFiles='/home/raed/Desktop/workfolder'

cd $SourceFiles

for video in *.mkv; do
        filename=${video%.*}
        #### This command normal without shown progressbar
        # ffmpeg -n -loglevel error -i "$filename.mkv" -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset faster -tune film "$filename.mp4";
        #### This command to show progressbar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-progressbar-cli)
        #### Need to install (sudo apt inatall npm && npm install --global ffmpeg-progressbar-cli)
        ffmpeg-bar -i "$filename.mkv" -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset faster -tune film "$filename.mp4";
done

cd ~

echo ""
echo "**********************************"
echo "****** Converting Finished *******"
echo "**********************************"
echo ""

exit 0
```

What I need is to make this code to convert all videos from all directories ...
For example I have (Season 1, Season 2, Season 5, Season 10)
I need from script to go throw Season 1 and convert all videos with any extension without (mp4) then remove original videos after converted and keep just (mp4) after that do automaticky same things from other folders (Season 2, Season 5, Season 10) ..

Comment: Just change the first line to `SourceFiles="$1"` and then invoke the script from `find`

Comment: eg `find . -type d -name 'Season*' -execdir $(pwd)/my-script \;`

Comment: Just write a new script which  loops over the directories, and for each directory, calls the  script you have posted here. Of course in this case you won't hard code the value for  `SourceFiles`, but pass it as parameter.

Comment: @William Pursell .. I'm just add for example ... The directory always  not the same name such as (Season, Film, theatre ... etc)